# Edit current user's shell with ansible

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible, system-administration

I'm trying to push my dot files and some personal configuration files to a server (I'm not root or sudoer). Ansible connects as my user in order to edit files in my home folder.

I'd like to set my default shell to `usr/bin/fish`.
I am not allowed to edit `/etc/passwd` so

```
user:
  name: shaka
  shell: /usr/bin/fish
```

won't run.

I also checked the `chsh` command but the executable prompt for my password.

How could I change my shell on such machines ? (Debian 8, Ubuntu 16, Opensuse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using two ansible modules :

- ansible expect
- ansible prompt

First I record my password with a prompt :

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "my_password"
    prompt: "Enter password"
    private: yes
```

And then I use the module `expect` to send the password to the chsh command :

```
tasks:
  - name: Case insensitve password string match
    expect:
      command: "chsh -s /usr/bin/fish"
      responses:
        (?i)password: "{{ my_password }}"
      creates: ".shell_is_fish"
```

The `creates` sets a lock file avoiding this task to be triggered again. This may be dangerous because the shell could be changed after and ansible will not update it (because of the lock still present). You may want to avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is old, but I wanted to post this in case anyone else comes back here looking for advise like I did:

If you're running local playbooks, you might not be specifying the user and expecting to change the shell of user you're running the playbook as.

The problem is that you can't change the shell without elevating the privileges (`become: yes`), but when you do - you're running things as root. Which just changes the shell of the root user. You can double check that this is the case by looking at /etc/passwd and seeing what the root shell is.

Here's my recipe for changing the shell of the user running the playbook:

```
- name: set up zsh for user
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  vars:
    the_user: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
  tasks:
    - name: change user shell to zsh 
      become: yes
      user:
        name: "{{ the_user }}"
        shell: /bin/zsh
```

This will set the variable `the_user` to the current running user, but will change the shell of that user using root.

Comment: OP says that they do not have root/sudo privileges, so using `become` is useless to them. Nice answer despite that!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I do it:

```yaml
- name: Set login shell of user {{ ansible_env.USER }} to `/bin/zsh` with `usermod`
  ansible.builtin.command: usermod --shell /bin/zsh {{ ansible_env.USER }}
  become: true
  changed_when: false
```

Comment: `changed_when: false` is a code smell that goes Ansible idempotency best practices - this reports no change even when there's a change. I don't see a reason to ever use this over `ansible.builtin.user`, which I've shown in an answer.

Comment: Agree, I've only learned now about this module

Answer (score 1):

In order to change away from a task which ran `chsh` and always reported a change, I leveraged the `user` built-in instead:

```
- name: Ensure default shell is /bin/bash for "{{ ansible_user }}"
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
```

This comes with proper idempotency out of the box.

Answer (score -15):

**Ubuntu 16**

add first line in `~/.bashrc`

`/usr/bin/fish && exit`

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. Even if someone wanted to change his shell, you would use `chsh`. This is a total dirty hack.